# move_uploaded_file with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem trying to upload a file from a form. The form with the file input is created using ajax.

ajax-getForm.php

```
<input id="uploadCouponPhoto" name="uploadCouponPhoto" type="file">
```

Then I use javascript on a button

```
<input id="popup_couponBox_commandButton" type="button" onclick="javascript: coupons_apply();" value="Appliquer">
```

to execute another ajax file that saves the form.

ajax-saveCoupon.php

```
$customPhoto = @$_POST['uploadCouponPhoto'];
if(!empty($customPhoto)){
    $name = "coupon_".$idCoupon;
    $directory = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/resources/images/members/".$idMember;
    if(move_uploaded_file($customPhoto, $directory."/".$name)){
        echo "success";
    }
    else{
        var_dump($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']);
    }
}
```

However, the response of ajax-saveCoupon.php is always false. I've tried to see the errors using `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']` but this gives NULL.`var_dump($_FILES)` gives an empty array. I can also see `uploadCouponPhoto: C:\fakepath\small-logo2.jpeg` in the form data of ajax-saveCoupon headers. I'm wondering what I'm not doing correctly for this to work, is it because the move_uploaded_file is not in the same file as the input?

Thanks.

Comment: `@$_POST['uploadCouponPhoto'];` is bad. Use `isset` or `array_keys_exists` to check if the key exists.

Comment: How are you transmitting the file via ajax?

Comment: What does `coupons_apply` do?

Comment: `coupons_apply` makes the ajax request for ajax-saveCoupon.php. The form is passed as a parameter in the request.

Comment: @OlivierParenteau: Can we see the code for `coupons_apply`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply `POST` files with AJAX. You can use the FileReader API to read the file and build your own `multipart/form-data` request.

This is quite involved and there are many tutorials on how to do it. Good luck.